# Create pdf from a react component

Tags: reactjs, pdf, pdf-generation

I am looking to create a pdf from my react component. The react component is basically a shopping cart page and I want to share the cart in a PDF file with users over mail. I looked at various options like jsPdf but the problem with that approach is that it first converts to a canvas and then into an image, which makes the selection from the rendered pdf impossible. My users want to be able to select text from the PDF. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm using jsPdf in my project to generate simple reports based od redux-store data, and render to PDF using `doc.text` method. After generate report I definitely can select text from PDF.

Comment: Thanks, ur comment worked. Actually, my problem was that I had a table and I thought it would be better that to get WSYIWYG feel I should used html2canvas first to capture viewport. But doc.text definitely is helpful for text. For tables however, it was not suitable. There I found another method i.e. autotable and i used the jspdf-autotable package.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this shortly ago. I used Handlebars and html2pdf. With Handlebars, you can setData into your HTML file. It allows you to use If Statements and for each statement in your HTML file.
First I created the HTML with handlebars like so...

```
    <html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous" />
    <style>
        @page {
            @bottom-right {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
   
            }
        }

        .hr-golden {
            border-color: #d7b436;
            height: 1px;
            color: #d7b436;
            background-color: #d7b436;
        }

        .hr-black {
            margin-top: 0rem;
            margin-bottom: 0rem;
            border-color: black;
            height: 1px;
            color: black;
            background-color: black;
        }

        .left-side span {
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .right-side span {
            margin-left: 20px;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .tdl {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .tdr {
            text-align: right;
            font-size: 14px;
        }

        .golden {
            background-color: #d7b436;
        }

        .golden2 {
            background-color: #E5DDC0;
        }

        .golden-color {
            color: #d7b436;
        }

        .footer {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100px;
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row;
            justify-content: space-between;
            font-family: Arial Narrow, sans-serif;
        }

        .price {
            display: flex;
            max-width: 50%;
            min-width: 50%;
            height: 5vh;
            font-size: 50px;
            justify-content: space-between;
        }


        p {
            font-size: 10px;
        }

        .priceTag {
            font-size: 15px;
        }

        
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="report" class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-auto col-md-12 text-right">
                <img src="../Loggo.png" height="auto" width="200px" style="margin-bottom: 30px;" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr-golden" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left left-side">
                <span>{{leftSideText1}}</span> <br />
                <span>{{leftSideText2}}</span> <br />
                <span>{{leftSideText3}}</span> <br />
                <span>{{leftSideText4}}</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-1"></div>
            <div class="col-md-5 text-right right-side">
                <table style="width: 70%; margin-left: 30%;">
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdl" style="font-size: 16px;">BESTELL-NR.</td>
                        <td class="tdr" style="font-size: 16px;">{{rightSideText1}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdl">DATUM</td>
                        <td class="tdr">{{rightSideText2}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="tdl">KUNDEN-NR.</td>
                        <td class="tdr">{{rightSideText3}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 50px;">
            <div class="col-sm-auto col-md-12 text-center">
                <table class="table  table-sm" style="width: 100%; border: none;">
                    <thead style="max-height: 14px;">
                        <th class="text-left">PRODUKT</th>
                        <th class="text-center">EINHEIT</th>
                        <th class="text-center">ANZAHL</th>
                        <th class="text-right">PREIS</th>
                        <th class="text-right">GESAMT</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        {{#each data.lists}}

                        {{#each this.orderers}}

                        {{#each this.products}}

                        <tr style="max-height: 14px">

                            <td class="text-left" style="font-size: 14px;">{{this.product.parent.name}}</td>
                            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 14px;">{{this.product.weight}} kg</td>
                            <td class="text-center" style="font-size: 14px;">{{this.amount}}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <div
                                    style="display: flex; padding-left: 35%; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">
                                        €
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">
                                        {{this.product.price}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <div
                                    style="display: flex; padding-left: 35%; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">
                                        €
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">
                                        {{this.total}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {{/each}}
                        {{#if_eq this.name 'initiator'}}

                        {{else}}


                        <tr class="golden" style="max-height: 14px; font-size: 14px; align-items: center;">
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-left" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">{{this.name}}</td>
                            <td class="text-right" style="font-size: 14px;">SUMME</td>
                            <td class="text-right" style=" border-top: black 1px solid;">
                                <div
                                    style="display: flex; padding-left: 35%; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">€ </p>
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">
                                        {{this.total}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {{/if_eq}}
                        {{/each}}
                        <tr class="golden2" style="border-bottom: black 2px solid; padding-bottom: 20px;">
                            <td colspan="3" class="text-left" style="padding-bottom: 8px;">{{this.name}}</td>
                            <td class="text-right">SUMME</td>
                            <td class="text-right">
                                <div
                                    style="display: flex; padding-left: 35%; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center;">
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">
                                        €
                                    </p>
                                    <p class="priceTag" style="margin: 0">
                                        {{this.total}}
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        {{/each}}


                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                <span>GESAMTSUMME INKL. STEUER</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <span>€ {{sumField5}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr-black" />
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 text-left">
                <span>GESAMTMENGE</span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 text-right">
                <span>{{sumField3}} KG</span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr class="hr-golden" />

        <div class="footer">
            <div class="footer-box-1">
                <p>
                    {{footerHeader}}
                    <br>
                    <span class="golden-color">
                        {{footerSection11}}
                    </span>
                    <br>
                    {{footerSection12}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-box-2">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    {{footerSection21}}<br>
                    {{footerSection22}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-box-3">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    {{footerSection31}}<br>
                    {{footerSection32}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-box-4">
                <p>
                    <br>
                    {{footerSection41}}<br>
                    {{footerSection42}}
                </p>
            </div>
            <div class="footer-box-5">
                <p>
                    <span class="golden-color">
                        <br>
                        {{footerSection51}}
                    </span>
                    <br>

                    {{footerSection52}}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Then I created a function in my React-App. This function is called when the download button is clicked.
This function looks like this:

```
const ExportOrder = async e => {


    await $.get('../../templates/report.html', async html => {
        const template = await Handlebars.compile(html);
        const htmlString = await template({
            logoUrl: `https://media.macphun.com/img/uploads/customer/how-to/579/15531840725c93b5489d84e9.43781620.jpg`,
            leftSideText1: `${order.customer.firstName} ${order.customer.lastName}`,
            leftSideText2: `${order.shipping.address1}`,
            leftSideText3: `${order.shipping.postcode} ${order.shipping.city}`,
            leftSideText4: `${order.shipping.country}`,
            rightSideText1: `${order.orderNumber}`,
            rightSideText2: `${order.date ? dateFormat(order.date, 'yyyy-mm-dd') : dateFormat(Date(), 'yyyy-mm-dd')}`,
            rightSideText3: `${order.customer.customerId}`,
            data: data2, //get from DB or JSON or wherever you want
            footerHeader: `asdfsadf`,
            footerSection11: `Gasdfasdf`,
            footerSection12: `Basdf`,
            footerSection21: `Wasdf`,
            footerSection22: `IBAN: asdfasdf`,
            footerSection31: `T +asdfasdf`,
            footerSection32: `BIC: Sasdfasdf`,
            footerSection41: `INFOsdfasdf`,
            footerSection42: `asdfasdf`,
            footerSection51: `tesdf`,
            footerSection52: `Text`,
            sumField3: amountSum,
            sumField5: data2.total.toLocaleString('DE-DE', { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 })
        });

        const opt = {
            margin: 0.5,
            filename: `bestellung.pdf`,
            image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
            html2canvas: { scale: 2 },
            jsPDF: { unit: 'in', format: 'letter', orientation: 'portrait' },
            dpi: 300,
            letterRendering: true,
            useCORS: true,
            pagebreak: { mode: ['avoid-all', 'css', 'legacy'] }
        };

        html2pdf().set(opt).from(htmlString)
    }, 'text');

}
```

The first line in the function is to get your HTML with jQuery which you have created first. Then it does fill the HTML with the data and you get an htmlstring. Which is generated to the pdf by html2pdf in the last line with the given options.

Comment: Are you fetching the html page from the server or does it reside on the client?

Comment: It will be generated on client-side. And the HTML is also on the client side